# How to schedule a periodic task in Java?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a task to run in at fixed interval of time. How can I do this with support of long intervals (for example on each 8 hours)?

I'm currently using `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`. Does `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` support long time intervals?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

Use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
 scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 8, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: If you want this to run every day at a specific time there's not a great way to do it, because the `TimeUnit` applies to both the `initialDelay` and the `period`. Running every 24 hours will end up being thrown off when DST kicks in, but a `TimeUnit` of `DAYS` doesn't let you specify a fine-grained `initialDelay`. (I think the internal ScheduledExecutorService implementation converts `DAYS` to nanoseconds anyway).

Answer (score 49):

You should take a look to [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) it's a java framework wich works with EE and SE editions and allows to define jobs to execute an specific time

Answer (score 31):

Try this way ->

Firstly create a class TimeTask that runs your task, it looks like:

```
public class CustomTask extends TimerTask  {

   public CustomTask(){
 
     //Constructor

   }

   public void run() {
       try {
     
         // Your task process

       } catch (Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("error running thread " + ex.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Then in main class you instantiate the task and run it periodically started by a precised date:

```
 public void runTask() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


    
        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object

        // Start running the task on Monday at 15:40:00, period is set to 8 hours
        // if you want to run the task immediately, set the 2nd parameter to 0
        time.schedule(new CustomTask(), calendar.getTime(), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8));
}
```

Comment: To make the code more readable you could change the final argument in you schedule call to TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(8)

Comment: The documentation for Timer recommends using the Executor framework instead.

Answer (score 14):

Use Google Guava `AbstractScheduledService` as given below:

```
public class ScheduledExecutor extends AbstractScheduledService {

   @Override
   protected void runOneIteration() throws Exception {
      System.out.println("Executing....");
   }

   @Override
   protected Scheduler scheduler() {
        return Scheduler.newFixedRateSchedule(0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }

   @Override
   protected void startUp() {
       System.out.println("StartUp Activity....");
   }


   @Override
   protected void shutDown() {
       System.out.println("Shutdown Activity...");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       ScheduledExecutor se = new ScheduledExecutor();
       se.startAsync();
       Thread.sleep(15000);
       se.stopAsync();
   }
}
```

If you have more services like this, then registering all services in ServiceManager will be good as all services can be started and stopped together. Read [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ServiceExplained) for more on ServiceManager.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to stick with `java.util.Timer`, you can use it to schedule at large time intervals. You simply pass in the period you are shooting for. Check the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 9):

Do something every one second

```java
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: The documentation for Timer recommends using the Executor framework instead

Answer (score 8):

These two classes can work together to schedule a periodic task:

### Scheduled Task

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;

// Create a class extending TimerTask
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    Date now; 
    public void run() {
        // Write code here that you want to execute periodically.
        now = new Date();                      // initialize date
        System.out.println("Time is :" + now); // Display current time
    }
}
```

### Run Scheduled Task

```
import java.util.Timer;

public class SchedulerMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Timer time = new Timer();               // Instantiate Timer Object
        ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(st, 0, 1000);             // Create task repeating every 1 sec
        //for demo only.
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Execution in Main Thread...." + i);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            if (i == 5) {
                System.out.println("Application Terminates");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/

Comment: Best solution until now, more clean and easy to implement

Answer (score 6):

If your application is already using Spring framework, you have [Scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) built in

Answer (score 5):

I use Spring Framework's feature. (*spring-context* jar or maven dependency).

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class ScheduledTaskRunner {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("TempFilesCleanerExecution")
    private ScheduledTask tempDataCleanerExecution;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = TempFilesCleanerExecution.INTERVAL_TO_RUN_TMP_CLEAN_MS /* 1000 */)
    public void performCleanTempData() {
        tempDataCleanerExecution.execute();
    }

}
```

***ScheduledTask*** is my own interface with my custom method ***execute***, which I call as my scheduled task.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [JobRunr](https://www.jobrunr.io/en/), an easy to use and [open-source Java Scheduler](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr).

To schedule a Job every 8 hours using JobRunr, you would use the following code:

```java
BackgroundJob.scheduleRecurrently(Duration.ofHours(8), () -> yourService.methodToRunEvery8Hours());
```

If you are using Spring Boot, Micronaut or Quarkus, you can also use the `@Recurring` annotation:

```java
public class YourService {

    @Recurring(interval="PT8H")
    public void methodToRunEvery8Hours() {
        // your business logic
    }

}
```

JobRunr also comes with an embedded dashboard that allows you to follow-up on how your jobs are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried **Spring Scheduler** using annotations ?

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/8 ? * * *")
public void scheduledMethodNoReturnValue(){
    //body can be another method call which returns some value.
}
```

you can do this with xml as well.

```
 <task:scheduled-tasks>
   <task:scheduled ref = "reference" method = "methodName" cron = "<cron expression here> -or- ${<cron expression from property files>}"
 <task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 0):

my servlet contains this as a code how to keep this in scheduler if a user presses accept

```java
if(bt.equals("accept")) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler=Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    String lat=request.getParameter("latlocation");
    String lng=request.getParameter("lnglocation");
    requestingclass.updatelocation(lat,lng);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a `ScheduledFuture` class in java.util.concurrent, it may helps you.