# java - How do you make something like a thread that can be started and stopped?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

Is there a way to make something like a thread that does something every x amount of ms that I can start, stop, and resume when I want it to? I know that a thread can be started but there is no real safe way to stop and resume a thread.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 4):

Here are a bunch of examples on how to start/stop periodic tasks in Java:

- [How to schedule a periodic task in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java) (basically executor service)
- [Schedule periodic tasks](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54) (a more detailed exploration into various ways to schedule periodic tasks)

The example from the first link:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 8, 8, HOURS);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class to schedule tasks on a background worker thread.

Comment: ScheduledExecutorService is a better alternative.

Comment: @Scorpion: If the task is simple, there is no need to use more complicated constructs.

Comment: Tudor: using ScheduledExecutorService isn't complicated (atleast not more complicated than using Timers) as illustrated by @Lirik's answer. Also, this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice) discussion should give you some insight why Timer should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The javadocs of the thread pol executor has an example of creating a thread pool which can be paused/ resumed. Here is the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

It is not of industrial strength but should be enough to give you ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the Timer class, which will allow you to periodically executes the run method of a sub-class of TimerTask.

For recurring events, the example given at http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html (slightly modified and copied here for convenience) is :

```
 public class AnnoyingMessage {
    Timer timer;

    public AnnoyingBeep() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
                       0,        //initial delay
                       1*1000);  //subsequent rate = once a second. 
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        int numWarningBeeps = 3;
        public void run() {
            if (numWarningBeeps > 0) {
                System.out.println(" MESSAGE!");
                numWarningBeeps--;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Done");
                timer.cancel(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely safe ways to stop threads. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html. And pausing a thread and resuming it is simply a matter of setting a flag and using `wait` and `notifyAll` appropriately.

You're probably looking for a higher-level abstraction, though. Have a look at [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29).