# how to start a process in certain time in java?

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, timertask

*i have one application which get the start and end time from the user and start the particular process at (start time) runs upto  the (end time),for sample i use TimerTask utility in case  it only start the  process from the current time and runs upto (end time) i cant set the start time how do i comapare the user time(start time) and system time in java*

```
//my sample  program
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

     int numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture=1000;

//    start time= dynamically set by user
//    end time =dynamically set by user


    Date timeToRun = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + numberOfMillisecondsInTheFuture);//here is the problem.
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {

      //System.out.println("doing");
      //doing some task not related to this question
      }
    }, timeToRun);
  }
```

Comment: What is the data type/format the user sets the time with and is the user in the same time zone as the application runs in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this helps 
[How i can run my TimerTask everyday 2 PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375882/how-i-can-run-my-timertask-everyday-2-pm)
You may have to do some changes to fit to your use.