# Will an infinite 'while loop' consume excessive resources

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I want to trigger a Java code at specific timing, let say every morning 1 AM.

I write a thread as below:

```
while (true) {
    if (currentTime = 1AM) {
        doSomething;
    }       
}
```

I am a bit worry, the **`while loop`** keep running, will it slow down the machine, or eating up processing resource?

My first question is, I am thinking if I only loop 1 time per second, will it better?

```
while (true) {
    if (currentTime = 1AM) {
        doSomething;
    }       

    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

My second question is, some time I see **`while loop`** written as below, most of time to acquire the Java lock, can anyone explain how expensive if we write the **`while loop`** like below (sorry if this is very basic question)?

```
while (isLock) {
    // do nothing
}

doThisIfNoLock();
```

I extend the thought above, if I create a empty thread, and an infinite empty **`while loop`** inside, how many resource (processing power) that actually eating up by the thread? Because there is no content inside the loop, based on my imagination, the loop will be running very fast, and end up taking many cycles of CPU power? Is that true?

Comment: There are schedulers to do such things. Look at Quartz Scheduler. If you are using Spring, you can schedule such things. Your approach is bad

Comment: Even `java.util.Timer` is better than what you are attempting.

Comment: You can not run infinite while loop.. It will suck the resources and slow down the processing. Use schedulers instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375882/how-i-can-run-my-timertask-everyday-2-pm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its not a good practice to run a infinite while loop as it can hog the CPU.

For Scheduled tasks you can use either libraries like Quartz or use `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask`

Your Task needs to inherit from `TimerTask` and override the `run()` method.
And then you need to use `Time.schedule()` method to schedule your task.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.sleep` can be used in this scenario however a better option would be using a timer similar to this

```
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();   
while(current < expectedElapsedTime){
    current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //logic goes here
}
```

Running a infinite loop without some sort of timer to slow the loop down will suck all your resources out of your computer like a vacuum. Another way you can schedule tasks is with a swing timer

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    checkUser = true;
  }
};
Timer checkUserTimer = new Timer(5000, listener); // 5 second pause
checkUserTimer.start(); // start the timer.
```