# How to create a method that will work automatically once a day

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to schedule a periodic task in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java)

I need to write a method (in a thread) that will work automatically everyday at 00:05.
(method will be run on server).

I've looked it up in Google and on this site but all results were about different languages (mostly C#). How do I achieve that in Java?

Comment: Does it have to be Java? Can you just use cron (Linux) or crontab (Windows)?

Comment: Is the program going to run all day and only execute at 00:05? Or does it do other operations?

Comment: it has to be JAVA. i need to run a specific task on my DB at 00:05... the server itself is running all day long.

Answer (score 2):

It could be useful to take a look to [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) project.

[Here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/) you can find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scheduler executor service; it has an option to run a task periodically (fixed rate). [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) should help you get started.

You should explore a third party library like quartz if you expect your scheduler based requirements to get complicated or grow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java EE, you can use the TimerService, here is a tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you could take.  Look at the [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for a java solution without a lot of dependencies.

You could also use Spring to leverage additional capabilities, and a more streamlined approach as is listed is this bit of [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled).