# call method on server startup

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am trying to call a method when my webapplication starts. The purpose is to kick-off a timer that does some work at defined intervals.
how do i call a function helloworld when my jboss 7.1 web application starts up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other then ContextListeners, you can also have a servlet in web.xml loading on startup:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mytask</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.MyTaskServlet</servlet-class>
    ...
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

This servlet can start your task using whatever means you want, see for example this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java).

But you shouldn't use that approach, imho.

Use a proven framework/lib like [quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) or a similar tool. There are a lot of problems/issues in running and syncing tasks in web servers and it's better to use some proven tool than to repeat mistakes these tools already met and solved. It might take a little while to grasp but will avoid many headaches.

Jboss itself has some tooling for that purpose: scheduling and managing tasks. Never used so can't recommend.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run some code before your web app serves any of your clients you need a ServletContextListener.

Create your listener class

```
import javax.servlet.*;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
   //Call your function from the event object here
 }

 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {

 }
}
```

Put the class in WEB-INF/classes

Put a <*listener*> element in the web.xml file.

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
     com.test.MyServletContextListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can i add Http server start code within contextInitialized method

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). You can use a [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) to fire at defined intervals. For example, every 5 minutes would look like this:

`"0 0/5 * * * ?"`

The idea is to implement the `Job` interface which is the task to run, schedule it using the `SchedulerFactory`/`Scheduler`, build the `Job` and `CronTrigger` and start it.

There is a very clear example [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/Example3).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) configured in your `web.xml`. Write the code that kicks off the timer in the `contextInitialized` method.