# Is it possible to pass method parameter to annotation on a method?

Tags: java, annotations

Let's say we have this method with annotation:

```
@Cached(key="search" + id)
public static List<String> search(String id) {
    //...
}
```

I want to pass parameter "id" to the @Cached annotation's key.

Is it possible to do this in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify a class definition's annotation string parameter at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268981/modify-a-class-definitions-annotation-string-parameter-at-runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible.

Attributes of Java Annotations must be constant expressions as defined by the Java Language Specification (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

I think your question has been answered before:
[Get rid of "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509065/get-rid-of-the-value-for-annotation-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-me)