# How to assign the class name to the property of an annotation in java without hardcoding

Tags: java

I am trying to write something similar to

```
@Property(name="className",value=MyClazz.class.getName())
class MyClazz{
}
```

But the compiler complains :

> The value for annotation attribute Property.value must be a constant
>   expression

Is there a workaround for this? or should i just hard-code the class name.

Comment: @Property is  from where?

Comment: Take a look trough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509065/get-rid-of-the-value-for-annotation-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-me

Answer (score 2):

Using the `Class` value type instead of `String` will support the following usage:

```
@MyQualifier(String.class)
String myMethod() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Your annotation type would be:

```
...
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyQualifier {
    Class value();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Java. However there is a workaround toward this problem. I would recommend to use [apt-constant-generator](https://github.com/wnameless/apt-constant-generator), this APT processor generates all related Constants of a Java class for your needs.

BTW, I am the author of the library.