# RequestParam.defaultValue value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting:

```
The value for annotation attribute RequestParam.defaultValue must be a constant expression
```

but I have declared MAX_LONG_AS_STRING as a constant (static final):

```
private static final String MAX_LONG_AS_STRING = Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE);

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String spittles(@RequestParam(value = "max", defaultValue = MAX_LONG_AS_STRING) long max, 
                       @RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "20") int count, 
                       Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("spittleList", spittleRepository.findSpittles(Long.MAX_VALUE, 20));
    return "spittles";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression" message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509065/get-rid-of-the-value-for-annotation-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-me)

Comment: Hahaha, the example is actually from the book "Spring in Action" (https://www.amazon.com/Spring-Action-Covers-4/dp/161729120X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1490873783&sr=1-1&keywords=spring+in+action)!

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
@RequestParam(defaultValue = Long.MAX_VALUE + "") long max
```

Answer (score 3):

As [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38844268/5065092) annotation take a compile-time constant. This may not be the solution you are looking for but to solve the problem at hand, `Long.MAX_VALUE` equals **`9223372036854775807`**

So you can do like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String spittles(@RequestParam(value = "max",defaultValue = "9223372036854775807") Long max,
                           @RequestParam(value = "count", defaultValue = "20") int count,
                           Model model){
        model.addAttribute("spittleList",spittleRepository.findSpittle(max,count));
        return "spittles";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a *compile-time* constant; `Long.toString()` isn't evaluated until runtime. You'll need to inline it (though it's usually better to omit it entirely if possible, and the new QueryDSL support might make building the repository query simpler).