# Can I pass a properties value inside @Query annotation?

Tags: java

Can I pass a properties value inside `@Query` annotation ?
My purpose is to pass native query as such to `@Query` notation.
So, whenever a change is made, i need to update the properties file value only.

Say this getQuery method returns a properties file value;

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface HerRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, String> {

String queryVal= SqlQueries.getQuery("herself");

@Query(name = "herNameQuery", value = queryVal, nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findHerName();
```

When i tried to use, I am getting this error like,

*Value of an annotation Query.value must be a constant expression.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get rid of "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509065/get-rid-of-the-value-for-annotation-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-me)

Comment: What is the main benefit of editing a property file instead of a constant?

Answer (score 0):

your string has to be a constant expression.
Have you tried :

private static final String QUERY_VAL = SqlQueries.getQuery("herself");

?