# Spring controller Path not being considered a constant

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller, constants

I'd like to define a Spring's controller path with a path variable as:

```
private static final String IDS_REGEX = "[" + EnumSet.allOf(MyIdsEnum.class).stream().map(MyIdsEnum.class::getValue)
  .collect(Collectors.joining("|")) + "]";
public static final String MY_PATH = "/path/{id:" + IDS_REGEX + "]}";
```

And then in my controller:

```
 @PostMapping(value = MY_PATH, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

However, IntelliJ throws an error in the PostMapping value:

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

The path is already static final, what should I have to do to turn it into a constant?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509065/get-rid-of-the-value-for-annotation-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-me

Comment: Is there a workaround to do what I'd like to?

Answer (score 0):

It must be a compile time constant.

A compile-time constant expression is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a String that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:

- Literals of primitive type and literals of type String
- Casts to primitive types and casts to type String
- [...] operators [...]
- Parenthesized expressions whose contained expression is a constant expression.
- Simple names that refer to constant variables.
- Qualified names of the form TypeName . Identifier that refer to constant variables.