# Spring cron using @Scheduled annotation does not pick up the expression from property file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

I am trying to read cron expression from the property file for `@Scheduled annotation`.

However, when I start the server, I get error like below

```
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'scheduleServicePrincipalOrchestorJob': For input string: "'0
```

Not Sure what is happening here.

My annotation looks like -

```
@Scheduled(cron= "${abc.cronExpression}", zone="America/Los_Angeles")
```

My application.properties looks like

```
abc.cronExpression="0 8 0 0 0 0"
```

Any leads on what is going wrong?

Comment: Remove the `"` in your properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from the cron expression. Also some of the fields cannot be 0, so start with a valid expression like this and adjust to your needs:

abc.cronExpression=0 0/5 * * * ?

That is, at second 0, every 5 minutes, every day.

Answer (score 0):

A cron expression in Spring using `@Scheduled` is consists of the following parts:

```
<second> <minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week> <year>
```

Where the last part `<year>` is optional.

In your example, you use both 0 for `<day-of-month>` and `<month>` which is not possible as they are not starting from 0 but 1.

Your cron works with the following two adjustments:

```
bc.cronExpression=0 8 0 * * 0
```

Where `*` means any day in the month for any month.

Or you can use the following to execute your code only at the first day of the first month:

```
bc.cronExpression=0 8 0 1 1 0
```

For more information, Bealdung put together a [great guide](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions) to cron expressions that may help you understand it further.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer to this.

The value for annotation attribute Scheduled.cron must be a constant expression

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16509088/4258006