# How to pass base package as a variable inside pointcut expression in Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, spring-aop, pointcut

I am creating a java library for logging purpose so that if any application uses my library then spring AOP's advices are applied to each method of the application. But in my library, I don't know the base package of the applications that will be using it. So, the applications should specify their base package in the *application.properties* file and my library will use it and put it in my pointcut as a variable. But seems like pointcut expressions only accepts contants inside it.

I don't want to go for annotation based approach.

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Slf4j
public class LoggingAop {

    @Value("${base.package}")
    String basePackage;

    @Pointcut("within("+basePackage+"..*)") //error
    public void logAllMethods()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers for the following questions explains why this is not possible with annotation based Spring AOP configuration

- [Get rid of "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression" message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16509065/4214241)
- [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065937/4214241)

Spring boot supports xml based configurations and the requirement can be achieved as follows.

Assuming we have to intercept all the method calls within base package `com.app.service`

Have an entry in resources/application.properties.

```
base.package=com.app.service
```

An Aspect to log method calls within the base package can be as follows

```
package com.app.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class LogAspect {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogAspect.class);

    public Object logAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        log.info("Log before method call");
        try {
            return pjp.proceed();
        }finally {
            log.info("Log after method call");
        }
    }
}
```

The aop configuration can be defined as follows .

File : resources/aop-application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

<bean id="logAspect" class="com.app.aspect.LogAspect"></bean>  

<aop:config>  
  <aop:aspect id="logallaspect" ref="logAspect" >  
     <!-- @Around -->  
     <aop:pointcut id="logAllMethodsAround" expression="within(${base.package}..*)" />  
     <aop:around method="logAllMethods" pointcut-ref="logAllMethodsAround" />  
  </aop:aspect>  
</aop:config>

</beans>
```

Do note that the pointcut expression is constructed with the application.properties entry.

Remember to load the aop-application-context.xml as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:aop-application-context.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The above code will advice all the interceptable Spring bean method calls within the defined base package and logs them .

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just wanted to write an almost identical answer. Thank God I refreshed the page before I started. Very good explanation!

Comment: @kriegaex Thank you , that comment means a lot to me. I have learned a lot from your answers here .

Comment: @R.G Thank you so much