# Java: How to provide value to annotation attribute fetched from a properties file?

Tags: java, annotations, constants, webservice-client

It always say that *The value for annotation attribute WebServiceClient.wsdlLocation must be a constant expression*.

But i need to load value from properties file as on QA/Prod/SIT, the URL is different.

How can i manage same in annotation?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rid of "The value for annotation attribute must be a constant expression" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509065/get-rid-of-the-value-for-annotation-attribute-must-be-a-constant-expression-me)

Comment: Actually that one is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java

Comment: You can’t. But the framework surely provides alternatives to annotation based configuration.