# Best way to schedule certain task in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I'm working on Java web application which requires running certain task (mysql query) once a day. What is the best way to do such thing in Java?

I saw something like Quartz but I'm not sure if it is ok for job like this. With quick review it looks like quartz requires initialization. Can it be done with web application? What about downtimes?

Comment: There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java

Answer (score 1):

quartz is a great solution (the [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler) tells you how to start it in a servlet container).  it's also a very popular solution so there is plenty of documentation online.

if you are running within a full j2ee container, there is a built in timer service.