# Should i use a while(true)

Tags: java

I am planning on building a webservice client that always checks for some records in the database and performs certain decisions based on results of the database content at each moment in time.

So i was thinking, how could i make the client run always ?

The only thing that came into my mind is to have an endless loop. Something like :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  while(true)
  {
     //Do database operation.
  }
}
```

So is this the right way of doing something like what i explained ?

Comment: You should read about java threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: whoy not use scheduler http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html ?

Comment: Would running at a specified schedule suit this use case? More info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java

Comment: A Timer would be nicer. Check (empirically) what the update interval is for data base queries. Inspect the sent headers for times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of an infinite loop on a server isn't necessarily a bad idea. It's prevalent in [tutorials that explain writing servers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). Typically, I don't tend to put this in my main method, but rather encapsulate it in a separate thread. I also typically don't use `true`, but some variable that can be toggled so that on some action (a message from a client, a key press, GUI actions, etc.), I can set that variable to false to stop execution of the server.

However, you may want to look at other [concurrency options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html), such as [pausing execution of threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) so you aren't always performing the action or the [Executor interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) for managing threads (especially the Scheduled Execution facilities).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a perfect use case for a scheduler, then you will be able to control your refresh ratio. Read [How to schedule a periodic task in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java) for your options.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much wrong in this, just add a Thread.sleep(milliseconds) value in your loop for a breather. otherwise you could probably look at a light scheduler which could call the method at regular intervals.