# Creating an automatic scheduler to stream tweets at a certain time each day

Tags: java, automation, scheduler, twitter4j

I'm relatively new to Java. I'm using Twitter4J to stream tweets live but only if I physically run it. How do I schedule to let it run at say, 12pm each day without physically running the program from my IDE?

Will appreciate if there are tutorials or so on this.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you running in? If you're running on Linux you can schedule a [cron job](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) to invoke the program and send tweets on a regular schedule.

Comment: In that case you can use the 'Task Scheduler' under windows.