# What is the way to make an infinite loop in a thread? android

Tags: android, multithreading, loops

I want to make an infinite loop in android, to check if some apps are active.
What is the best way to do this without using too much cpu?

Maybe a while loop or a handler or something?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
import android.os.Handler;

// Create the Handler
private Handler handler = new Handler();

// Define the code block to be executed
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Insert custom code here

      // Repeat every 2 seconds
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
    }
};

// Start the Runnable immediately
handler.post(runnable);
```

To remove the execution of the runnable:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: To escape the error "runnable might not have been initialized" I have created an array before the `runnable` declaration

`final Runnable [] runnables = new Runnable[1];` and I've replaced the line `handler.postDelayed` to this line `handler.postDelayed(runnables[0], 2000);`

Comment: I am a beginner. My lessons says that I should avoid inner class for it may cause memory leaks. So won't this cause the same?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
while(true)
```

Just make sure to use a `break` when you want to exit.

You also could do something like this:

```
boolean run = true;
while(run)
{
    if()//Whatever you want to cause the loop to stop.
    {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use an infinite loop in a thread.  I would use a scheduled task like this.  From [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java)

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
     scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnable, 8, 8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Then you can customize how frequently you want it to run by changing the `TimeUnit` to however frequently you need the thread to run.