# Adding timeout to a user interface program

Tags: java, button, timeout, actionlistener

I'm working on a Java project involving user interface, using the Button class and some action listeners.
I have a few buttons (each with an action listener) and I want to add a timeout to the whole program. That means, if no button was clicked-on in a certain amount of time, a specific action should be performed.

I tried adding it among the basic while loop + isDisposed() function. To my knowledge, this loop checks multiple times whether a button was clicked-on. For some reason, I couldn't get the outcome I wanted.
Is there a way to do so with the classes I mentioned? I also couldn't find any suitable functions in the Button class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Swing Timer ([javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)).

Instanciate it with `new Timer(CERTAIN_AMOUNT_OF_TIME, e -> timeoutAction())` (If you have a function timeoutAction), disable repeating with `setRepeats(false)` and `start()` it.

When the user clicks a button, call `restart()` on it.

Also, you’re mentioning the Button class, which is an AWT class. I recommend using Swing’s JButton class instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly probable that you are using swing, but since this is not specified, I will give you a general answer, with links to swing examples.

First of all, since all your button clicks will behave in a very similar manner, so you will need a custom `ActionListener` ([example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)). Your custom action listener should perform the action, but set a [timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) or some kind of date value to the current moment. In parallel, you should have a heartbeat event, which periodically (frequently) runs and compares the current moment with the timestamp set by the last button click. And you can see an example of a periodic task here: [How to schedule a periodic task in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java)